# Docker cp parameter expansion in powershell

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-cp

I would like to run something like this:

```
$docker_container_name = "iar_build_container"
...
$cp_arguments =  $docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug " + $docker_artifacts + "/Debug"

"Copying out the build artifacts: $cp_arguments"
docker cp "$cp_arguments"
```

The output of this is:

```
Copying out the build artifacts: iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug ./docker_artifacts/Debug
"docker cp" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker cp --help'.

Usage:  docker cp [OPTIONS] CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH|-
        docker cp [OPTIONS] SRC_PATH|- CONTAINER:DEST_PATH

Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem
```

If I hard code the docker cp command it works, and if I use the following it works:

```
docker cp iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug $docker_artifacts/Debug
```

So I am having an issue expanding what would be the first parameter that is the container name and colon.

EDIT:
This works, but it feels hacky:

```
$cp_arguments = "cp " + $docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug " + `
                        $docker_artifacts + "/Debug"

"Copying out the build artifacts: $cp_arguments"
Start-Process -FilePath "docker" -ArgumentList "$cp_arguments" -Wait
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on @nishaygoyal answer. Running executables (e.g. docker) in PowerShell is different than running executables in CMD prompt. In PowerShell, arguments are passed as an *array of strings*, and not as a space separated series of strings like in CMD prompt. Hence by passing the space separated string of arguments, PowerShell is interpreting it as a single argument, and a single string.

Hence, by simply changing your arguments into an array of strings, and moving the "cp" as one of those items. Things will work:

```
$docker_container_name = "iar_build_container"
$docker_artifacts = "./docker_artifacts"

$cp_arguments = @("cp",                                               `
                  "$($docker_container_name):C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug",  `
                  "$docker_artifacts/Debug")

docker $cp_arguments
```

**EDIT:**

As @Nick pointed out, we have to use the subexpression operator:  `$($docker_container_name)` in the string to do proper string expansion because PowerShell will interpret `$docker_container_name:C:` as a variable instead of `$docker_container_name`. To PowerShell, the colon indicates the scope of the variable, e.g. `$global:foo`. So we need to use the subexpression operator `$()` to properly define our variable for string expansion.

---

Why does using `Start-Process` like this work?

```
$cp_arguments = "cp " + $docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug " + `
                        $docker_artifacts + "/Debug"

Start-Process -FilePath "docker" -ArgumentList "$cp_arguments" -Wait
```

Well, according to [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-7#parameters) it's special in that the `-ArgumentList` can accept a space separated list of arguments, and it treats them in a CMD prompt style way.

We also can use [EchoArgs](https://chocolatey.org/packages/echoargs) to see exactly what is being passed as arguments:

```
$docker_container_name = "iar_build_container"
$docker_artifacts = "./docker_artifacts"

#Original:

$cp_arguments =  $docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug " + $docker_artifacts + "/Debug"

PS C:\> EchoArgs.exe docker cp "$cp_arguments"
Arg 0 is <docker>
Arg 1 is <cp>
Arg 2 is <iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug ./docker_artifacts/Debug>

Command line:
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\echoargs\tools\EchoArgs.exe" docker cp "iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug ./docker_artifacts/Debug"
```

(Notice that we are passing 2 arguments, `cp`, and the rest of the string. vs. passing an array:

```
$cp_arguments = @("cp",                                               `
                  "$($docker_container_name):C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug",  `
                  "$docker_artifacts/Debug")

PS C:\> EchoArgs.exe docker $cp_arguments
Arg 0 is <docker>
Arg 1 is <cp>
Arg 2 is <iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug>
Arg 3 is <./docker_artifacts/Debug>

Command line:
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\echoargs\tools\EchoArgs.exe" docker cp iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug ./docker_artifacts/Debug
```

In this case, you can see it splits out the arguments "correctly"

Comment: In your array example, the variable `$docker_container_name` is not expanded. I tried `$docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug"` for the second array element, but it looks like that is getting split.

Comment: This did the trick: `"$($docker_container_name):C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug", `

Comment: Ah yes, `$docker_container_name:C:` gets interpreted by PowerShell as a variable, (which is empty) and so the string expansion doesn't "work" as expected. Indeed, you have to use the subexpression operator `$(..)`  to properly separate out the variable from the rest of the string and have the string expansion happen properly. I have edited the answer with the corrected code.

Answer (score 2):

The way you defined it, `docker cp` is actually considering `$cp_arguments` as 1 string and that's why it's complaining about 2 arguments Have a look below

```
docker cp "iar_build_container:C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug $docker_artifacts/Debug"
```

And if you try to run it in this fashion it will fail.

Try the below approach in which you don't pass `""` to `$cp_arguments`

```
docker cp $cp_arguments
```

You have already defined another way in the question which is a bit hacky butone more approaches would be.

```
$docker_container_name = "iar_build_container"
...
$cp_arguments_src =  $docker_container_name + ":C:/docker_work/IAR/Debug "
$cp_argument_dest =  $docker_artifacts + "/Debug"

"Copying out the build artifacts: $cp_arguments"
docker cp "$cp_arguments_src" "$cp_argument_dest"
```